# Removing "duplicates" from mailing-list/forum RSS feeds

Tags: discussion, chat

In many of our chat rooms (e.g. the [Quantum ESPRESSO one](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117642/quantum-espresso)), we use RSS feeds to inform us when new discussions take place on mailing lists or forums. However we get feed items posted not only when new questions are asked, but also when answers or responses are posted. This can make the chat room quite noisy, with not much (if any) added benefit, as you can see in the example below:

[image]

One way to solve this problem would be to edit the RSS file itself, to remove such duplicates. Does anyone have any ideas about what the best way to do that would be?